# Sources of Eddy current and hysteresis in linear materials

Tags: electromagnetism, magnetic-fields, electric-fields, electricity, electromagnetic-induction

Following is an excerpt about transformer on load from *Kothari and Nagrath, Electrical Machines*.

> The value of exciting current $i_0$ has to be such that the required MMF is established so as to create the flux demanded by the applied voltage. If a linear B-H relationship is assumed (devoid of hysteresis and saturation) the exciting current is only magnetising in nature and proportional to the sinusoidal flux and in phase with it. This is represented by the phasor **I**$\text{}_m$ lagging the induced emf by $90°$. However the presence of hysteresis and the phenomenon of eddy currents, though of different physical nature, both demand the flow of active power into the system.

What is meant by "... *though of different physical nature*...." here? I mean if the core is linear, is it the coil causing hysteresis? Please shed some light with proper reference.

Comment: Both hysteresis and eddy currents are dissipative in nature. The coil does not cause hysteresis, the ferromagnetic core does.

Comment: @hyportnex Then why is the author saying they are of different nature, while assuming a linear B-H curve at the same time?

Comment: An *ac* linear B-H implies a lossless core. If the core is not an ideal insulator then the induced eddy currents in it, hence the appellation to "ac", will dissipate being of a "different nature" than otherwise would be; my reading.